# Throw error for unclosed comment block javacc

Tags: comments, lexer, javacc

I am creating a lexer in javacc that skips block comments that start with /* and end with */. I have it working correctly for valid block comments but I am trying to figure out a way to throw an error when a block comment is unclosed...

Example:

```
/* this is not a valid block comment
/* this is a valid block comment*/
```

Here is what I have to skip valid block comments:

```
MORE: { <"/*"> : BLC_CMNT_ST}
<BLC_CMNT_ST> SKIP: { <"*/">: DEFAULT >
<BLC_CMNT_ST> MORE: { <~[]>}
```

Currently when I run the lexer a TokenMgrError is thrown when there is unclosed block comment. I would like to catch this error and/or throw my own error that displays the matchedToken.image. I have tried a few different ways but have ran into issues so any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SKIP: { <"/*"> : BLC_CMNT_ST}
<BLC_CMNT_ST> SKIP: { "*/" : DEFAULT  }
<BLC_CMNT_ST> SKIP: { < ~[] > }

<*> TOKEN : { <EOF>
    { System.out.println("Lexical state is " + curLexState ) ; 
    if(curLexState==BLC_CMNT_ST) throw new Error("Unmatched comment at end of file.") ; } }
```

I had to use SKIP instead of MORE for reasons I don't fully understand.

If you want to disallow "/*" inside of block comments you can add this production

```
<BLC_CMNT_ST> TOKEN: { < "/*" > 
    { if(true) throw new Error("Unmatched comment at line "
                   + matchedToken.beginLine
                   + ", column "
                   + matchedToken.beginColumn + ".") ; } }
```

Unfortunately this solution does not give you access to the image of the comment.